# How to recover loaded Kate Plugins

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kate

Dear stackoverflow users:

So far I was working well with kate when I installed it in ubuntu 16.04 as sudo apt-get install kate.

However, some days ago. I got the following error when launching kate:
**org.kde.kwindowsystem: Could not find any platform plugin**

I have tried removing, the app and reinstalling it, deleting the ./kde folder and the same remains.

Do you know how to fix it back to the original configuration?
Thank you

Comment: Same message out of the blue using Ubuntu 18.04 and launching okular.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your 16.04 installation to a more recent one. Many things improved, and this issue will also be resolved. I don't think this is Kate's fault here.